# Show that $\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{3!~n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, asymptotics

> Show that $\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{3!~n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$.

In fact, this result is pretty obvious but when I did this in homework I basically got no points because I was to shallow in my reasoning. So here is my new attempt.

---

**Proof:**

We know that the Taylor series at point $0$ of $\sin(x)$ exists so the "tail" $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}$ of it also exists.

Basically, we now want to show that there exist a constant $C>0$ and an index $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ it holds: $\Big|\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}\Big|\leq C \cdot \frac{1}{n^5}$ which is equivalent to saying $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}=O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$.

For this we show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^5\cdot\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}$ converges.

Because $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}$ converges we are allowed to perform the multiplication with a fixed $n$: $n^5\cdot \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k-4}}$.

Now the question is what happens to $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k-4}}$ if $n\to\infty$? Again, this seems very obvious as $n$ only appears in the denominators but my tutor said that this is not a rigorous argument. So I guess that we must find a closed form expression for $\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k-4}}$ or we must at least find an upper bound which attains a closed form expression. I would simply take a geometric series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k}=\frac{1}{n-1}$ as $\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k-4}}\leq\frac{1}{n^k}$ holds for all $n$ and $k$.

Hence, for all $n$ we have:
$$
0\leq n^5\cdot\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k-4}}\leq \frac{1}{n-1}\\\implies \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^5\cdot\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}=0.
$$
So for a constant $C>0$ we find an index $n_0$ which is large enough such that for all $n>n_0$:

$$\Big|n^5\cdot\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}\Big|<C \\\implies \Big|\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}\Big|<C \frac{1}{n^5}\\\implies 
\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!~~n^{2k+1}}=O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\\\implies
\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{3!~n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right).
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I didn't check your work, but I just wanted to mention that you can use the [mean-value form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) (what you call the "tail"), which will simplify your proof that it is $O(n^{-5})$.

Comment: The shortcut used in your title is awful!

Comment: Are you allowed to use limits and the L^Hopital's rule?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz, at which step would I need L'Hopital? Actually, I don't think that I need L'Hopital in my approach. Or is it flawed?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net what do you mean by that? Do you refer to the Lagrange form of the remainder as suggested by angryavian? I just want to know if my approach is correct or not.

Comment: @Philipp, your approach is perfectly fine, but another way in my opinion is to find the following limit$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\sin x-x+{x^3\over 6}\over x^5}.$$Finding the limit value (using L^Hopital here) would yield the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment on the Approach in the Question**

It would be more rigorous to cite Dominated Convergence as a reason that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^5\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^k\frac1{(2k+1)!}\frac1{n^{2k+1}}=-\frac1{120}
$$
thereby bounding the remainder of the series.

One could also bound by a geometric series:
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^k\frac1{(2k+1)!}\frac1{n^{2k+1}}\right|
&\le\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{120n^{2k+1}}\\
&=\frac1{120\!\left(n^5-n^3\right)}
\end{align}
$$

However, both of these approaches require that you have either defined $\sin(x)$ as its Taylor series, or that you've shown that the Taylor series converges, which seems to be doing more than this question asks, so circularity is a concern.

---

**Another Approach**

Integrate by parts $4$ times:
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(x)
&=\int_0^x\cos(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=x-\int_0^x(x-t)\sin(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=x-\frac12\int_0^x(x-t)^2\cos(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=x-\frac16x^3+\frac16\int_0^x(x-t)^3\sin(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{24}\int_0^x(x-t)^4\cos(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=x-\frac16x^3+O\!\left(x^5\right)
\end{align}
$$
Since
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^x(x-t)^4\cos(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right|
&\le\left|\int_0^x(x-t)^4\,\mathrm{d}t\right|\\
&=\frac15|x|^5
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Does it mean that my approach is wrong?

Comment: I am pointing out why your tutor might have claimed your approach lacks rigor. Whether someone finds your approach "wrong" depends on how rigorous they want the argument to be. They might also claim it is circular unless they accept the Taylor series as defining $\sin(x)$.